# Sicstus Prolog - Weight of a word

Tags: prolog

I've got a problem about how to weigh a word.
Every single letter in a word has specific weight, I need to calculate the total weight of the word.
For example:

```
A-E = 1,  F-O = 2, P-Z = 3.
```

If the word is "PEN", the answer will be "Weight = 6",

```
cuz P = 3, E = 1 and N = 2.
```

I've tried:

```
word_weight([X], W):-
    X = 65 -> W = 1;
    X = 66 -> W = 3.
word_weight([X,Y],W):-
    X = 65 -> W1 = 1;
    X = 66 -> W1 = 3,
    Y = 65 -> W2 = 1;
    Y = 66 -> W2 = 3,
    W is W1 + W2.
word_weight([X|Y], W):-
    X = 65 -> W = 1;
    X = 66 -> W = 3,
    word_weight(Y, W).
```

Running res:
| ?- word_weight("B",W).
W = 3 ? 
yes

It only works with one letter. How to make it works with many letters? And the answers will be the total value of the weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program works with SWI-Prolog. It will be surely easy to adapt it to Sicstus Prolog.

```
char_weight(C, 1) :- C >= 65, C =< 69.
char_weight(C, 2) :- C >= 70, C =< 79.
char_weight(C, 3) :- C >= 80, C =< 90.

word_weight([], 0). 
word_weight([Char| Chars], Weight) :- 
    char_weight(Char, W), 
    word_weight(Chars, Ws),
    Weight is W + Ws.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
weight(C, 1) :- char_code('A') =< C, C =< char_code('E').
weight(C, 2) :- char_code('F') =< C, C =< char_code('O').
weight(C, 3) :- char_code('P') =< C, C =< char_code('Z').

word_weight(S, W) :- string(S), !, string_list(S, L), word_weight(L, W).
word_weight([], 0).
word_weight([H|T], W) :- W is weight(H) + word_weight(T).
```

in ECLiPSe-CLP, [string_list/2](http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/stratom/string_list-2.html) converts a string into a list of numberic character codes, [char_code/2](http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/termmanip/char_code-2.html) gets the numeric code of a character.

**Edit:**
Oops, I should have read your question completely:

- Wen using `->/2`, you should use brackets and don't hesitate to use indentation:
  `( Condition ->
      IfBranch
  ;
      ElseBranch
  ),
  RestProg.`
  Your second clause is a bit unreadable. But for this excercise you shouldn't need `->/2` at all.
- Your third clause only works for a single-letter string, because it first unifies W with the value for X and then wants to unify W with the weight of X. This only works if Y and X have the same weight.